# How to create virtual directories in PHP?

Tags: php, virtual-directory

I want to create an application in PHP implementing virtual directory feature.
Example: `http://mydomain.com/user001` will display the contents of the url `http://mydomain.com/index.php?user=user001`. How can I do that?

**Note:**
I am using Apache server.

Comment: Take a look at e.g. [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) or the [Symfony Routing Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/introduction.html). Better to use well-proven components than rolling your own stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The traditional way to do it is [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Comment: If I want to do that for a blogging application then I have to do mod_rewrite for every entry. Example: Every time I create a question in stackoverflow.com, it automatically creates a virtual directory for that question.

Comment: no, you'd set up a regex in your rewrite rule to match any entry.

Answer (score 2):

Please read [this friendly article regarding rewrite](http://www.noupe.com/php/10-mod_rewrite-rules-you-should-know.html).

Next, try to find a simple way in PHP to parse this variable $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].

After doing that, you have the name of the directory and you can get its data from the DB.

Answer (score 0):

Intercept the HTTP request using the 'REQUEST_URI' element of $_SERVER. This returns (I believe) only the requested page, not the entire URI/URL - more info [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php). Once you've grabbed the page request, substitute the address of the actual file that's needed. For example, the user-friendly ***www.somewebsite.com/page01*** becomes a request for the more clunky-sounding ***www.somewebsite.com?page01.php***. This method won't create a virtual directory, as such, but should work okay. I have used a similar method on my own [IT website](http://www.northdevonitservices.co.uk), where each page is loaded via index.php, allowing that file to keep a log of visitors in real time (the site has Webalizer, which runs a day or so in arrears).

Rewriting the filename might work, although it's not to my personal taste. Using PHP to effect a URI/URL-swap would likely carry the benefit of reduced server demand, due to requiring less disk read/write time than filename rewrites.

I hope that helps.